# How to pivot a date range in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset like this:

```
sID   Key   date 
-----------------------
AAA   123   2009-05-27 
AAA   457   1985-01-01
BBB   890   1900-01-01
BBB   785   2008-09-05
```

I want to have a pivoted view of the dates, it should look like this :

```
sID   Key   start_date   end_date
-----------------------------------
AAA   123   2009-05-27   2050-12-30
AAA   457   1985-01-01   2009-05-26
```

The end date of the second column should not overlap with the start date of the first column. The end date of the first column is just a random date I chose

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on SQL Server 2012+ and the input table does not have duplicate dates for any given ID, you can use the [lead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) analytic function:

```
select sID
     , Key
     , start_date
     , lead(dateadd(day, -1, start_date) -- one day before the `start_date`
            , 1, '99990101')             -- from the "next" row (or a special value if this is the last row)
         over (partition by sID          -- grouping rows by sID
               order by start_date asc)  -- "next" row assuming ordering by ascending start_date
       as end_date
from ...
```

Comment: what is start_date in the first select?

Comment: @koala Sorry, it's the field called `date` in your first table.

Comment: ps: after `Key,` there is an unwanted comma

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want `lag()` function

```
select sid, Key, date as start_date,
       lag(dateadd(day,-1,[date]), 1, <default_date>) 
                   over(partition by sid order by ?) as end_date
from table t;
```

`?` specifies your actual ordering cols.